# bitwise AND in Javascript with a 64 bit integer

Tags: javascript, 64-bit, integer, bit-manipulation

I am looking for a way of performing a bitwise AND on a 64 bit integer in JavaScript.

JavaScript will cast all of its double values into signed 32-bit integers to do the bitwise operations ([details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)).

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/q/3637702/632951

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Javascript represents all numbers as 64-bit [double precision IEEE 754 floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double-precision_64_bit) (see the [ECMAscript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), section 8.5.)  All positive integers up to 2^53 can be encoded precisely.  Larger integers get their least significant bits clipped.  This leaves the question of how can you even represent a 64-bit integer in Javascript -- the native number data type clearly can't precisely represent a 64-bit int.

The following illustrates this.  Although javascript *appears* to be able to parse hexadecimal numbers representing 64-bit numbers, the underlying numeric representation does not hold 64 bits.  Try the following in your browser:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript">
      function showPrecisionLimits() {
        document.getElementById("r50").innerHTML = 0x0004000000000001 - 0x0004000000000000;
        document.getElementById("r51").innerHTML = 0x0008000000000001 - 0x0008000000000000;
        document.getElementById("r52").innerHTML = 0x0010000000000001 - 0x0010000000000000;
        document.getElementById("r53").innerHTML = 0x0020000000000001 - 0x0020000000000000;
        document.getElementById("r54").innerHTML = 0x0040000000000001 - 0x0040000000000000;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="showPrecisionLimits()">
    <p>(2^50+1) - (2^50) = <span id="r50"></span></p>
    <p>(2^51+1) - (2^51) = <span id="r51"></span></p>
    <p>(2^52+1) - (2^52) = <span id="r52"></span></p>
    <p>(2^53+1) - (2^53) = <span id="r53"></span></p>
    <p>(2^54+1) - (2^54) = <span id="r54"></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox, Chrome and IE I'm getting the following.  If numbers were stored in their full 64-bit glory, the result should have been 1 for all the substractions.  Instead, you can see how the difference between 2^53+1 and 2^53 is lost.

```
(2^50+1) - (2^50) = 1
(2^51+1) - (2^51) = 1
(2^52+1) - (2^52) = 1
(2^53+1) - (2^53) = 0
(2^54+1) - (2^54) = 0
```

---

So what can you do?

If you choose to represent a 64-bit integer as two 32-bit numbers, then applying a bitwise AND is as simple as applying 2 bitwise AND's, to the low and high 32-bit 'words'.

For example:

```
var a = [ 0x0000ffff, 0xffff0000 ];
var b = [ 0x00ffff00, 0x00ffff00 ];
var c = [ a[0] & b[0], a[1] & b[1] ];

document.body.innerHTML = c[0].toString(16) + ":" + c[1].toString(16);
```

gets you:

```
ff00:ff0000
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case I am actually reading in a binary string containing a 64-bit value. So I could somehow turn that into two 32 bit numbers and use my own internal representation to manage that data.

Comment: Hey Toby; what do you mean by binary string?  If this is a sequence of characters, each of which is the character equivalent of an 8-bit byte, you could do: var a = [ s.charCodeAt(0) + (s.charCodeAt(1) << 8) + (s.charCodeAt(2) << 16) + (s.charCodeAt(3) << 24), s.charCodeAt(4) + (s.charCodeAt(5) << 8) + (s.charCodeAt(6) << 16) + (s.charCodeAt(7) << 24) ]; Just keep an eye on the endian-ness of things.

Comment: @Orent Trutner: be careful here: with Unicode, a char code could exceed 255. I think that your code fails as soon as one of the bytes has the high bit set.

Comment: Indeed. To-date, I am still not clear on how the OP's 64-bit numbers were originally represented. "a binary string", as in the first comment, could mean 8-bit characters, 16-bit characters, or even a string of 64 "0" and "1" characters.

Comment: Here is some more info if you use javascript with WinRT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710232(v=vs.94).aspx A Windows Runtime Int64 is a signed 64-bit integer, represented as a standard number if it falls within the range [-2^53, 2^53].

Comment: You can also use Closure's goog.math.Long class. See the and() method: http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_math_Long.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It tells me that what I want to do is not possible, but I'm sure it is.

Answer (score 19):

Here is code for AND int64 numbers, you can replace AND with other bitwise operation

```
function and(v1, v2) {
    var hi = 0x80000000;
    var low = 0x7fffffff;
    var hi1 = ~~(v1 / hi);
    var hi2 = ~~(v2 / hi);
    var low1 = v1 & low;
    var low2 = v2 & low;
    var h = hi1 & hi2;
    var l = low1 & low2;
    return h*hi + l;
}
```

Comment: Note that to use another bitwise operation you would replace `&` in the expressions for `h` and `l`.

Comment: This is great, what about left/right shift << and >> ?

Comment: @vanowm Example: 10 << 3 can write 10 * (2 ** 3), and 10 >> 3 can write Math.floor(10 / (2 ** 3))

Answer (score 15):

This can now be done with the new BigInt built-in numeric type. BigInt is currently (July 2019) only available in certain browsers, see the following link for details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

I have tested bitwise operations using BigInts in Chrome 67 and can confirm that they work as expected with up to 64 bit values.

Answer (score 6):

Javascript doesn't support 64 bit integers out of the box. This is what I ended up doing:

1. Found [long.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js), a self contained Long implementation on github.
2. Convert the string value representing the 64 bit number to a `Long`.
3. Extract the high and low 32 bit values
4. Do a 32 bit bitwise *and* between the high **and** low bits, *separately*
5. Initialise a new 64 bit `Long` from the low and high bit
6. If the number is > 0 then there is correlation between the two numbers

**Note**: for the code example below to work you need to load
    [long.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js/blob/master/src/long.js).

```
// Handy to output leading zeros to make it easier to compare the bits when outputting to the console
function zeroPad(num, places){
    var zero = places - num.length + 1;
  return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join('0') + num;
}

// 2^3 = 8
var val1 = Long.fromString('8', 10);
var val1High = val1.getHighBitsUnsigned();
var val1Low = val1.getLowBitsUnsigned();

// 2^61 = 2305843009213693960
var val2 = Long.fromString('2305843009213693960', 10);
var val2High = val2.getHighBitsUnsigned();
var val2Low = val2.getLowBitsUnsigned();

console.log('2^3 & (2^3 + 2^63)')
console.log(zeroPad(val1.toString(2), 64));
console.log(zeroPad(val2.toString(2), 64));

var bitwiseAndResult = Long.fromBits(val1Low & val2Low, val1High & val2High, true);

console.log(bitwiseAndResult);
console.log(zeroPad(bitwiseAndResult.toString(2), 64));
console.log('Correlation betwen val1 and val2 ?');
console.log(bitwiseAndResult > 0);
```

Console output:

> 2^3
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000
>
> 2^3 + 2^63
>
> 0010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000
>
> 2^3 & (2^3 + 2^63)
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000
>
> Correlation between val1 and val2?
>
> true

Answer (score 4):

The Closure library has [`goog.math.Long`](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.math.Long.html) with a bitwise `add()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer (and others) appears not to have been adequately tested. Confronted by this problem recently, I initially tried to split my 64-bit numbers into two 32-bit numbers as suggested, but there's another little wrinkle.

Open your JavaScript console and enter:

```
0x80000001
```

When you press Enter, you'll obtain 2147483649, the decimal equivalent. Next try:

```
0x80000001 & 0x80000003
```

This gives you -2147483647, not quite what you expected. It's clear that in performing the bitwise AND, the numbers are treated as signed 32-bit integers. And the result is wrong. Even if you negate it.

My solution was to apply ~~ to the 32-bit numbers after they were split off, check for a negative sign, and then deal with this appropriately.

This is clumsy. There may be a more elegant 'fix', but I can't see it on quick examination. There's a certain irony that something that can be accomplished by a couple of lines of assembly should require so much more labour in JavaScript.