# How to calculate Hemming Distance in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, user-defined-functions, hamming-distance

Each item in my collection has a 64-bit number, which represents dhash of the image. I want to run a query by this field, which will return all items, that have Hamming Distance more or less than some param.

In MySQL I would use BIT_COUNT function. Is there any built-in analog of it in CosmosDB? If no, then how my HAMMING_DISTANCE UDF should look like since JS doesn't support bitwise operations on 64-bit numbers?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983206/bitwise-and-in-javascript-with-a-64-bit-integer

Comment: Good news everyone! "Work on this feature has started. Will update here when complete" said Azure Cosmos DB Team on the feedback portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I took code from [long.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/Long.js/) and [ImageHash](https://github.com/coenm/ImageHash) for using in CosmosDB UDF.  All cudos to their authors.

See gist it here https://gist.github.com/okolobaxa/55cc08a0d67bc60505bfe3ab4f8bc33c

Usage:

```
SELECT udf.HAMMING_DISTANCE(files.ContentId, '1279796919517872320') FROM files
```

But please note a few things:

1. CosmosDB doesn't support 64-bit numbers as numbers, you have to
   store them as strings.
2. Using this UDF costs a lot of RUs

I created a feature request on the CosmosDB Feedback forum to add built-in support of such functions. Please vote for these ideas if you're interested in it too:

- [Built-in functions for bitwise operations](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/41745799-built-in-functions-for-bitwise-operations)
- [Built-in functions for calculating distance metrics](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/41745865-built-in-functions-for-calculating-distance-metric)