# bitwise XOR in Javascript with a 64 bit integer

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, xor, uint64, bitwise-xor

I am looking for a way of performing a bitwise XOR on a 64 bit integer in JavaScript.

JavaScript will cast all of its double values into signed 32-bit integers to do the bitwise operations.

I already found this function in [bitwise AND in Javascript with a 64 bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983206/bitwise-and-in-javascript-with-a-64-bit-integer)
for bitwise AND and seems to work ok, but still need the XOR.

```js
function and(v1, v2) {
    var hi = 0x80000000;
    var low = 0x7fffffff;
    var hi1 = ~~(v1 / hi);
    var hi2 = ~~(v2 / hi);
    var low1 = v1 & low;
    var low2 = v2 & low;
    var h = hi1 & hi2;
    var l = low1 & low2;
    return h*hi + l;
}
```

For the XOR Func this is  the transformation i have done but is not working properly, any help modifying it would help me.

```js
function XOR(v1, v2) {
    var hi = 0x80000000;
    var low = 0x7fffffff;
    var hi1 = ~~(v1 / hi);
    var hi2 = ~~(v2 / hi);
    var low1 = v1 ^ low;
    var low2 = v2 ^ low;
    var h = hi1 ^ hi2;
    var l = low1 ^ low2;
    return h * hi - l;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript numbers don’t have 64-bit precision. Are you aware of that? You might want an array of `[high, low]` 32-bit integers instead, which are also more straightforward to work with. (Or a `BigInt`, if performance isn’t a concern.)

Comment: Use a `BigInt`.

Comment: The `and` implementation seems quite understandable. Please show us your attempt at transforming the code into an `or` implementation. Hint: you need to change only five characters!

Comment: Please link the source *where* you found that `and` function if you didn't write it yourself.

Comment: You changed 8 characters in your attempt. 5 of them would've been enough.

Comment: Do you understand what each line in the code does? Can you try to explain them, please?

Comment: I dont understand all of it, but thats all i have, if you can explain it to me and point me to the right direction, its great with me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistakes in the lines

```
var low1 = v1 ^ low;
var low2 = v2 ^ low;
```

where it should be and & to recover the lower part of the number, and later perform the ^ xor operator in both sides

```
var low1 = v1 & low;
var low2 = v2 & low;
```

and the last line should be at the example with & operator a sum:

```
return h * hi + l;
```

Complete code above:

```js
function XOR(v1, v2) {
    var hi = 0x80000000;
    var low = 0x7fffffff;
    var hi1 = ~~(v1 / hi);
    var hi2 = ~~(v2 / hi);
    var low1 = v1 & low;
    var low2 = v2 & low;
    var h = hi1 ^ hi2;
    var l = low1 ^ low2;
    return h * hi + l;
}

const res = XOR(114616149816979, 383577466862359);
console.log(res);
```